# Why won't my Unit Tests run?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

My `karma.conf.coffee` is:

```
module.exports = (config) ->
  config.set
    basePath: '../../'

    preprocessors:
      '**/*.coffee': ['coffee']

    files: [
      'dist/assets/vendor.js'
      'public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
      'dist/assets/app.js'
      'test/public/**/*.coffee'
    ]

    singleRun: true

    frameworks: ['mocha']

    browsers: ['PhantomJS']

    reporters: ['story']

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO

    coffeePreprocessor:
      options:
        bare: true
        sourceMap: false
      transformPath: (path) ->
        path.replace(/\.coffee$/, '.js')
```

`vendor.js` is a concatenated js of `angular.js`, `angular-route.js` and `angular-strap.js`. `app.js` is all of my angular code concatenated.

I have a test: `test/public/controllers/login.spec.coffee` that looks like:

```
(->
  describe 'Login Controller', ->
    beforeEach module 'myApp

    it 'should initialize the controller', ->
      # createController()

      # $scope.init()
)()
```

When I run the test, I get:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) - Login Controller:
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)  "before each" hook: [object Object] FAILED
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) Login Controller "before each" hook: [object Object] FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'fn.call')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in most cases i agree, but man its the same answer! :-)

Comment: Hahahahahaha... Thanks for that I up voted urs as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a closing quote...

```
(->
  describe 'Login Controller', ->
    beforeEach module 'myApp' // <------ here you forgot it

    it 'should initialize the controller', ->
      # createController()

      # $scope.init()
)()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(->
  describe 'Login Controller', ->
    beforeEach module 'myApp

    it 'should initialize the controller', ->
      # createController()

      # $scope.init()
)()
```

You are missing a ' after myApp

```
    beforeEach module 'myApp'
```

always preview your coffeescript